# Ring Extension: Mapping: $ \mathbb Q[\sqrt d] \rightarrow \mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field

Show that the Norm: $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d] \rightarrow \mathbb Q, (r+s\sqrt d) (r-s\sqrt d) = r^2 - ds^2$ is multiplicative, i.d. $N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$

**How to show it without computing?**

*(I tried to do it by computing and went astray. If you know how to compute something like this compactly, please let me know.)*

The following is known/given.

$d \in \mathbb Z, \sqrt d \in \mathbb C$ is a zero of $x^2 - d$

$ \mathbb Q[\sqrt d] = \{r + s\sqrt d | r,s \in \mathbb Q  \} $

$ \mathbb Z[\sqrt d] = \{m + n\sqrt d | m,n \in \mathbb Z  \} $

$\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ and $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ are integrity domains, subrings of $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ is a field...

What if it could be shown that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d] \cong Quot(\mathbb Z[\sqrt d])$ and then use the fact that to say that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d] \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ is a ring homomorphisms or isomorphism.

**How to show $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d] \cong Quot(\mathbb Z[\sqrt d])$?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should be a little careful with your notation.  The ring extension is $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ and the field extension is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.  The field extension has to contain $1/\sqrt{d}$ and the ring extension does not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. For any $a \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ consider map $M_a: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}] \to \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ defined by $M_a(x) = ax$. This is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, and easy calculation shows that for $a = r + s \sqrt{d}$, $\det(M_a) = N(a) = r^2 - ds^2$. Now, clearly $M_a \circ M_b = M_{ab}$, so $N(ab) = \det(M_{ab}) = \det(M_a \circ M_b) = \det(M_a)\det(M_b) = N(a)N(b)$.

To elaborate why $\det(M_a) = r^2 - ds^2$: note that $a$ satisfies a polynomial equation $a^2 - 2 r a + (r^2 - d s^2) = 0$ -- in fact, this is miniml polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $M_a^2 - 2r M_a + (r^2 - d s^2)$ is a zero linear map, so $x^2 - 2rx + (r^2 - d s^2)$ is a characteristic polynomial of $M_a$. On the other hand, we know that for 2x2 matrix $M$, its characteristic polynomial is $x^2 - 2 \mathrm{tr}(M) + \det M$.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate you would like to know about directly computing this...

Let $x = s+t\sqrt{d}$ and $y = u+v\sqrt{d}$ be elements of $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$.  Then we compute \begin{align*}
      xy  &= su + dtv + (sv+tu)\sqrt{d}  \text{,}  \\
    N(xy) &= (su + dtv)^2 - d((sv+tu))^2  \\
      &= s^2u^2 + 2dstuv + d^2t^2v^2 - ds^2v^2 - 2dstuv - dt^2u^2  \\
      &= s^2u^2 + d^2t^2v^2 - ds^2v^2 - dt^2u^2  \text{, and} \\
    N(x) N(y) &= (s^2 - dt^2)(u^2 - dv^2)  \\
      &= s^2u^2 - ds^2v^2  - dt^2u^2 + d^2t^2v^2  \text{,}
\end{align*} and with a trifling rearrangement, we see $N(xy) = N(x) N(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

You ask how to show $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \cong \mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$, where I have altered your notation to indicate that the object on the left is a field extension (which is necessary, because the object on the right contains an element that it is not unreasonable to write as $1/\sqrt{d}$ (and which it is rigorous to write $\frac{1 + 0\sqrt{d}}{0+1\sqrt{d}}$).

Observe that $(\sqrt{d})^2 \in \Bbb{Z}$, so an arbitrary element of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $a + b \sqrt{d} + c/\sqrt{d}$ and an arbitrary element of $\mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$ is $\frac{s+t\sqrt{d}}{u+v\sqrt{d}}$.  We find \begin{align*}
    a+b\sqrt{d} + c/\sqrt{d} &= \frac{(bd + c) + a \sqrt{d}}{0+1\sqrt{d}}  \text{ and} \\
    \frac{s+t\sqrt{d}}{u+v\sqrt{d}} &= \frac{s+t\sqrt{d}}{u+v\sqrt{d}} \frac{u-v\sqrt{d}}{u-v\sqrt{d}}  \\
      &= \frac{su - dtv + (tu-sv) \sqrt{d}}{u^2-d v^2}  \\
      &= \frac{su - dtv}{u^2-d v^2} + \frac{(tu-sv) }{u^2-d v^2} \sqrt{d} + 0/\sqrt{d}  \text{.}
\end{align*}  If the maps $$  f:\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]): a+b\sqrt{d} + c/\sqrt{d} \mapsto \frac{(bd + c) + a \sqrt{d}}{0+1\sqrt{d}}  $$  and  $$  g: \mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]) \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}): \frac{s+t\sqrt{d}}{u+v\sqrt{d}} \mapsto \frac{su - dtv}{u^2-d v^2} + \frac{(tu-sv) }{u^2-d v^2} \sqrt{d} + 0/\sqrt{d}  $$ are inverses, we have the isomorphism you want.  So we compute  \begin{align*}
  f\left(\frac{su - dtv}{u^2-d v^2} + \frac{(tu-sv) }{u^2-d v^2} \sqrt{d} + 0/\sqrt{d} \right) &= \frac{\left( \frac{(tu-sv) }{u^2-d v^2}d + 0 \right) + \frac{su - dtv}{u^2-d v^2} \sqrt{d}}{\sqrt{d}}  \\
&= \frac{su - t\sqrt{d} \, \sqrt{d}v + (tu-sv)\sqrt{d}}{u^2- (v\sqrt{d})^2}  \\
&= \frac{s + t\sqrt{d} }{u + v\sqrt{d}}  \text{ and}  \\
g \left( \frac{(bd + c) + a \sqrt{d}}{0+1\sqrt{d}} \right) &= \frac{(bd + c)0 - da1}{0^2-d 1^2} + \frac{(a0-(bd + c)1) }{0^2-d 1^2} \sqrt{d} + 0/\sqrt{d}  \\
      &= a+b\sqrt{d} + c/\sqrt{d}  \text{.}
\end{align*}  So these maps are inverses and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \cong \mathrm{Frac}(\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$ as fields.

Comment: It is certainly no more rigurous to write the ugly $\frac{1+0\sqrt d}{0+1\sqrt d}$ that the good ol' $1/\sqrt d$...